# Create a blackoverlay or disable monitor

Tags: windows-7, display, c++, c, winapi

Part of an exercise I am creating to use a PC without a monitor(By that I mean only using a keyboard and a mouse and by heart knowing which buttons to click) requires to somehow disable it and let the student stop the process which created this black overlay or activating a script that enables the monitor again.

I have tried using the SendMessage in winapi but it only puts the monitor to sleep, which any mouse movement or keyboard click will disable. I have used this:

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
```

I have found that there is a registry which handles detection of new monitors in windows at HKLM > Software > Microsoft > TMM  > UseIViewHelper. Supposedly if you change it from 1 to 0 it stops detecting new monitors but doesn't seem to work(or at least for my understanding).

I tried using MultiMonitorTool by Nir Soffer, but it doesn't seem to disable a primary monitor, and as I have only one monitor to the PC it doesn't help at all.

Can anyone help me with an idea of how to do it, or maybe what tool I should use?

Thanks

Comment: You can draw garbage (or just black rectangle) directly on [desktop window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504(v=vs.85).aspx). Another heretic idea you could try would be custom color profile (ICC) to make everything black.

Comment: Couldn't you just press CRTL+ALT+DELETE and delete the black window process? Can you force the desktop window to be always on foreground?

And the custom color profile does sound heretic haha!

Comment: I have tried making a borderless and TopMost = true in c# which works pretty nicely though , the task manager bypasses it easily as well as recently used commands in run appear over the blank page..

Is there a way to fix these stuff?

Comment: Constantly drawing directly on desktop HWND "bypasses" always on top windows (like task manager) but mouse cursor should still be above. It is better than topmost window as it wont steal focus from underlying window.

Comment: How would one do so? I tried creating a rectangle and drawing it in a while(true) but it seems somewhat buggy and doesn't block everything. I feel like I am missing knowledge that I am not able to find in google. How would you write a rectangle that constantly redraws itself on the entire screen without stealing focus from any other window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have completed this task eventually using a few tricks, Here is how I did it:

1. Wrote a C# form with topmost = true property making infront of all possible windows except task manager, start menu and the taskbar.
2. Wrote in C# a function to change registry that enables task manager, and removed most options from the crtl+alt+del screen.
3. Added a function that activates a bat script that activates an AHK script to disable all crtl + alt + delete possiblities ( kinda disgusting, I know).
4. Created a function to remove the taskbar.
5. Altered the options of privacy manually by going: right click task bar > options > startmenu> unticking both options in privacy section.

Result:

A black overlay with no startmenu, no crtl+alt+del , no task manager , no alt tab. Yet everything you do is registered normally like the monitor is disconnected. Be careful when doing this as you might get stuck without an option out! I created another application that reverts all those stuff and added it to the run shortcuts so while not seeing anything I could blindly press CRTL+ R and write the shortcut I created to disable everything!

PM me if anyone would like the full source code.